# Expanding content to top

Tags: html, css

How do I expand my content to top instead of bottom? I'm trying to make the text go to top but it's always going to bottom. Here is my code =>

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}

.div {
  position: relative;
  transition: .35s ease-in-out 0s;
  height: 0;
  width: 70%;
  left: 50%;  
  top: 100px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  line-height: 155%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="div">
    <p class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My expected output is =>
[image]

I know that I'm using `top: 100px` in `.div` but is just to create an example. I'm aiming to the text always go to top, no matter the configuration.

I tried to manipulate `height, top and bottom` but no success, what should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to swap `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` in the `.box`- and `.div`-classes as follows:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .35s ease-in-out 0s;
  height: 0;
  width: 70%;
  left: 50%;  
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  line-height: 155%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="div">
    <p class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You had a lot of unnecessary code. And mess with position relative and absolute :D Here it is working well https://jsfiddle.net/ue6s3ap5/5/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.div {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px
}

.text {
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  line-height: 155%;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="div">
    <p class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```